# Water shut-off valve

Tags: kitchens

[image]

Does anybody know how to take off this kind of water valve I don't where to unscrew this water valve?

Comment: Have you tried getting a flat blade screwdriver under the black middle bit and prying upwards?

Comment: No I haven't try that but, thanks I guess the black plastic is some kind of lock